# django rest extensions drf-extensions TypeError at /data/ register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parents_query_lookups'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get a simple nested route set up with drf-extensions but am having trouble following the [docs](http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes), I am getting this error:
TypeError at /data/
register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parents_query_lookups'

Trying to achieve /data/Survey/<survey>/Version/<version>/Product/<product>/ 
each survey has multiple versions and those versions will contain multiple Products e.g., /data/survey/survey1_name/version/survey1_version1/product/survey1_version_product1/

but currently I have un-nested endpoints

/data/survey/

/data/versions/

/data/products/

models.py

```
class Survey(models.Model):
  survey = models.CharField(choices=SURVEYS, max_length=100)


class Version(models.Model):
  version = models.CharField(choices=DATA_RELEASES, max_length=50)
  survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey)


class Product(models.Model):
  product = models.CharField(choices=PRODUCTS, max_length=100)
  version = models.ForeignKey(Version)
```

views.py

```
class SurveyViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Survey.objects.all()
  serializer_class = SurveySerializer
  permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

class VersionViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Version.objects.all()
  serializer_class = VersionSerializer
  permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

class ProductViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Product.objects.all()
  serializer_class = ProductSerializer
  permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

serializers.py

```
class SurveySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Survey
    fields = ('id', 'survey')

class VersionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Version
    fields = ('id', 'version', 'survey')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
      model = Product
      fields = ('id', 'product', 'version')
```

urls.py

```
router = ExtendDefaultRouter()
router.register(r'surveys', views.SurveyViewSet, base_name='survey')
router.register(r'versions', views.VersionViewSet, parents_query_lookups=['survey']),
router.register(r'products', views.ProductViewSet, parents_query_lookups=['version'])


urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^data/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 5):

You should chain the calls to register(), instead of calling them directly on the router :

urls.py

```
router = ExtendDefaultRouter()
(router.register(r'surveys', views.SurveyViewSet, base_name='survey')
      .register(r'versions', views.VersionViewSet, parents_query_lookups=['survey']),
      .register(r'products', views.ProductViewSet, parents_query_lookups=['version']))
```

That's because NestedRouterMixin.register() returns an instance of NestedRegistryItem, which is the class that understand the `parents_query_lookups` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep your project well organized in accordance with the hierarchy of your data, the first thing I would do is separate each tier of urls into a separate entity, and possibly even a separate file.  The second would be to add an primary-key endpoint to each tier of the rest API. In the end it would look something like this:

**survey_urls.py**

```
router.register(r'survey', views.SurveyViewSet, base_name='survey')
router.register(r'survey-version/', include('my_app.rest_server.version_urls'))
```

**version_urls.py**

```
router.register(r'version', views.VersionViewSet, base_name='version')
router.register(r'version-product/', include('my_app.rest_server.product_urls'))
```

**product_urls.py**

```
router.register(r'product/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.ProductViewSet, base_name='product')
```

Then, your final url could look like: /data/survey-version/33/version-product/5/product/8

In all likelihood, this is an unnecessary complication of things, since each product has its own unique id, and then you can just access it with a url like: /data/product/pk, using a single url routing, namely the last line of code above.

My examples assumed the records have a numeric primary key, if the case is otherwise you'd have to change the regex accordingly.